# Is there anyone to get dynamic env value in seprate pod kubernetes k3s

Tags: kubernetes

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: mongodb-config
data:
    mapConfig: |
      - dbName: dbName-database1
        label: Database1
      - dbName: dbName-database2
        label: Database2
      - dbName: dbName-database3
        label: Database3
      - dbName: dbName-database4
        label: Database4

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: backend-server
spec:
  replicas: 4
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: backend-server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: backend-server
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: backend-server
          image: backend-server-image:latest
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          env:
            - name: DB_NAME
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: mongodb-config
                  key: mapConfig
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: "250m"
            limits:
              cpu: "500m"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
```

> apiVersion: v1
> kind: Service
> metadata:
>
> > > name: backend-server-service
> > > spec:
> > > type: LoadBalancer
> > > selector:
> > > app: backend-server
> > > ports:
> > >
> > > - protocol: TCP
> > >   port: 3000
> > >   targetPort: 3000

I have used the configMap but I got all the values in env is there any way that I can get the dbName unique in every pod

I got all the env but like I want
dbName: dbName-database1
label: Database1

In the first pod
rest like same for all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question: `is there any way that I can get the dbName unique in every pod`

I suggest you to create 4 different `Deployment`s as the idea of `Deployment`(and in the end `Pod`s) is to be exactly the same, but as you want to make it different, so you should have 4 different `Deployments`

Other way to minimize number of duplicated code is to use [helm](https://helm.sh) and create `chart`, because Kubernetes by default doesn't support dynamic values